What will happen if a user who initially have the bounty privilege but lost it during the duration of the bounty?
There's nothing in particular about this, just that I'm curious. Let's suppose a scenario: A user gains reputation, and got the "offer a bounty" privilege (awarded upon reaching 75 rep points). Then, they immediately offer a bounty worth 50 rep. However, due to some circumstances, the user's rep decreased by a large amount, whether due to downvotes, voting reversals, user deletions, spam or offensive penalties, post deletions, ...etc, and they lose the privilege of offering a bounty. Even so, the bounty they already offered is not yet expired. What will happen in such cases? Can anyone please explain this to me? The help center's bounty explanation doesn't help much. This doesn't cover this scenario either. I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

The link you gave above How does the bounty system work? clearly states in the first answer under the sub-question "How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?" The bounty award will be subtracted from your reputation when the bounty is started, not when it is awarded., so losing reputation after starting a bounty is irrelevant.

@PeterJames OK, thanks for pointing out. I didn't notice that. Again, thanks!

The privilege only covers offering bounties. You can award bounties you have already offered regardless your current reputation level.
You can offer a bounty even if the bounty spend, or any other subsequent events, bring you below the threshold of the set bounties privilege afterwards, and still be able to award the bounty. You just will not be able to set any more bounties until you regained the required reputation.

Thanks for your answer, it is very helpful. So basically put, the reputation after you offered the bounty does not affect the already offered bounty in any way. Thanks again for the explanation.

@LukeL Correct.

Something that is worth adding is suspension - one can't award a bounty when suspended. (So having 1 rep, though it's not directly related to the reputation.)
